# Magento 2: Get last 5 orders detail

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I have code for last order detail but I want last 5 orders.
For last order detail code is:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->getLastItem();
        $orderId   =   $orderDatamodel->getId();
        $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
        $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();

        foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
           $product_name=   $item->getName();         
           $product_id=   $item->getProductId();
        }
```

I want last 5 oders detail.

Comment: As per separate customer's last 5 order or all over last 5 order?

Comment: Last 5 in All orders.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: Sorry, but I stuck with the server so I cant save file right now. As possible as I give you a result.

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :) You can upvote also :) So, it will useful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below code. It maybe helpful for you :

```
$orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
$orderDatamodel->getSelect()->limit(5);
    foreach ($orderDatamodel as $key => $value) {
        $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($value->getId());
        $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
            $product_name = $item->getName();
            $product_id = $item->getProductId();
            echo $product_name . "--" . $product_id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give me hole code with loop like item name and items detail

Comment: $objectManager  without using how to get all orders imformation on home page in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

In below code orders has been set in descending order and `setPageSize()` will give you 5 records only.

```
$ordercollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
$ordercollection->setOrder(
    'created_at',
    'desc'
)
    ->setPageSize(5)
    ->setCurPage(1);

foreach($ordercollection as $order){
    echo $order->getRealOrderId();

    //To get order items
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo $item->getPrice();
        echo $item->getSku();
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- Don't use Object Manager.
- Inject OrderRepository or Interface Class

Comment: Can you give me Inject OrderRepository code for fetch last 5 order item name ?

Comment: Refer this class https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Sales/Api/OrderRepositoryInterface.php

Comment: Sorry, I am not that level of a programmer so this link does not solve my answer.

Comment: So the above answer not working for you to get result?

Comment: I didn't check I want whole code with loop I want order item name and details

Comment: refer to updated answer